# _Context.SaveChanges Reset foreign key values in other table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

for my system, every project can have a limited number of students (1 to M), so when I add or edit a student I always check against the database to check if max the number of students has been reached and if so, I will set a project property IsAvailable to false.
When I do so, all students Project IDs in the student table turn null, I have been trying to solve for a while, but I can't figure out the reason why is this happening.
Here is my code

```
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
        student,
        "student",
        s => s.Pnumber, s => s.CourseId, s => s.ProjectId, s => s.SupervisorId,
        s => s.SecondMarkerId, s => s.FirstName, s => s.LastName))
        {
            if (student.CourseId == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("student.CourseId", "Please Enter the Course of study");
                return Page();
            }

            await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();

            List<Project> Projects = (from pr in _Context.Project
                                      select pr).ToList();
            Projects = UpdateAvailability(Projects);
            foreach (var project in Projects)
            {
                await TryUpdateModelAsync<Project>(project);
                await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }                
            await TryUpdateModelAsync<User>(User);
            User.Email = student.Pnumber + "@my365.dmu.ac.uk";
            await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();                
            return RedirectToPage("./AllStudents");
        }
```

The UpdateAvailability function:

```
public List<Project> UpdateAvailability(List<Project> Projects)
    {
        foreach (var project in Projects)
        {
            List<Student> Students = (from st in _Context.Student
                                      where st.ProjectId == project.ProjectId
                                      select st).ToList();

            if (Students.Count == project.NumberOfStudents)
            {
                project.IsAvailable = false;
            }
            else if (Students.Count < project.NumberOfStudents)
            {
                project.IsAvailable = true;
            }
        }
        return Projects;
    }
```

Comment: Is it EF or EF Core ?

Comment: I am not sure but I am using .net core 2

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the beginning I think that you could be written better:

1. You are an unnecessary iterating list of projects twice. You can update the `IsAvailable` and do other things in one loop.
   [image]
2. Looks like there is an unnecessary save here (I don't see any changes to be saved here):
   [image]
3. Why are you calling save in the loop? One save after the loop should be enough:
   [image]

Now regarding your main issue. I don't see the whole code so it's hard to say why those IDs are cleared. But:

- what is `await TryUpdateModelAsync<User>(User)` doing - maybe something here is wrong?
- what do you have inside of the database? Maybe you have a trigger somewhere there which is turning those IDs into NULLs?

Comment: I understand point 1 and 3 I was just trying to find out where is the problem. For number 2 the save is for the project table. As for the last two points .. I update the user table to reflect any change in the email/p number .. the database have the tables and the keys constrains .. there no stored procedures .. what might be a problem in the database ?

Comment: I can insert ids to the database directly just fine, it doesn’t null the ids. The problem happens directly after the UpdateAvailability function, as I was checking the database table value changes

Comment: Is there any trigger (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms189799(v=sql.110).aspx) in the database? Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: No I didn’t create any triggers